# Copying an array to a string and displaying the string in order

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I am copying an NSMutableArray to a string. When I am displaying the string I am getting a "(" sign before the array items and the array entries are separated by a comma in between. I want to display the array entries line by line, and not by comma separated. How can I do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. If you just want to join the array with a new-line character, the easiest is to use `NSArray`'s [-componentsJoinedByString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003620) method. For example, to do exactly what you asked:

```
NSArray* myArray = // assume this exists
NSString* stringJoinedByNewLines = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
// This should show each of the elements separated by a new-line (and they are now in a single string)
NSLog(@"the string: %@", stringJoinedByNewLines);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSMutableArray * items = someArray;
    NSMutableString * bulletList = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:items.count*10];
    for (NSString * s in items)
    {
        [bulletList appendFormat:@"%@\n", s];
    }

yourTextView.text = bulletList;
```

Comment: You could append the bulletlist to anything you want,numbered lines dots or a combination, I just used a new line char:(\n).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
NSString*str=[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"\n"];
```

This will replace all the opening braces with a new line character.Do the same for closing brace.

Comment: That won't work. He's seeing the '(' and such because he's simply looking at the description of the array, which is formatted for viewing in the debugger/console logs. It's not actually a string formatted as such.

Comment: But still you are storing the array in the string,so ultimately it becomes a string,correct?

Comment: He didn't show the code, but if it displayed as a string, my guess is no. My guess is that he did something like `NSString* string = (NSString*)theArray;` and then tried to `NSLog()` the new `string`. That cast is a trick because the new object won't really be a string, it'll still be an array.

Comment: But either way, it's preferable to act on the objects as objects then try to coerce undocumented, debug-formatted output of objects into something else you want to use.

Comment: yeah dats correct,we need to find the way to convert NSArray to NSString.Then it all will work.

Comment: NSString *myArrayString = [array description]; was the code I used

Comment: I was displaying the string in a label in my tableview cell. Even in the cell, it showed the "(" sign.